# Deallocating the Memory Using free() makes the entire C program not print any allocated data?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

Pointers in C is a very hard subject for me. This is part of a code from my homework and it reproduces the problem that I am having.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define MAX_SONGS_PER_USER   10
#define MAX_USERS             5
#define MAX_ARTISTS         100


#define NUM_TEST_USERS      7


// This struct represents a song in the system
typedef struct {
    char      *title;
    char      *artist;
    short int  duration;
    char        downloaded;
} Song;

// This struct represents a user in the system
typedef struct {
    char       *name;
    char        online;                    // 1 = YES, 0 = NO
    Song       *songs[MAX_SONGS_PER_USER]; // songs this user has
    short int   numSongs;                  // number of songs this user has
} User;

// This structure represents the Tune Share system
typedef struct {
    User        *users[MAX_USERS];     // An array of all registered users
    short int    numUsers;
} TuneShare;

int registerUser(TuneShare *t, char *name)
{
    short int numUsers = t->numUsers;

    if (numUsers == MAX_USERS)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if(numUsers >= 1)
            //printf("%s \n", t->users[0]->name);
        for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++)
        {
            User *u = t->users[i];
            char *uName = u->name;
            if (uName == name)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            //free(u);
        }
        User *temp;
        if ((temp = malloc(sizeof *temp)) != NULL)
        {
            temp->name = name;
            temp->numSongs = 0;
            temp->online = '0';
        }
        
        t->users[numUsers] = temp;

        t->numUsers = numUsers + 1;

        return 1;
    }
}

int addSong(User *u, char *title, char *artist, short int duration)
{
    short int numSongs = u->numSongs;
    if (numSongs == MAX_SONGS_PER_USER)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (numSongs >= 1)
            for (int i = 0; i < numSongs; i++)
            {
                if (u->songs[i]->title == title)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        Song *temp;
        if ((temp = malloc(sizeof *temp)) != NULL)
        {
            temp->title = title;
            temp->artist = artist;
            temp->duration = duration;
        }
        u->songs[numSongs] = temp;
        u->numSongs = numSongs + 1;
        //free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
}

void logon(TuneShare *t, char *name)
{
    User *u = userWithName(t, name);
    
    if (u != NULL)
    {
        u->online = '1';
    }
}

void displayStats(TuneShare *t)
{
    printf("\nTune Share Center (%d registered users)\n", t->numUsers);
    short int numOnline = 0, numSongs = 0;
    User **u = onlineUsers(t, &numOnline);
    Song **s = allAvailableSongs(t, &numSongs);


    printf("\n%d Online Users:\n", numOnline);
    if (numOnline == 0)
    {
        printf("\tNONE\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOnline; i++)
        {
            printf("\t%s with %d songs as follows:\n", u[i]->name, u[i]->numSongs);
            for (int j = 0; j < u[i]->numSongs; j++)
            {
                printf("\t\t\"%s\" by %s\n", u[i]->songs[j]->title, u[i]->songs[j]->artist);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d Available Songs:\n", numSongs);
    if (numSongs == 0)
    {
        printf("\tNONE\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numSongs; i++)
        {           
            int min = s[i]->duration / 60;
            int sec = s[i]->duration % 60;
            if(sec > 10)
                printf("\t\"%s\" by %s (%d:%d)\n", s[i]->title, s[i]->artist, min, sec);
            else
                printf("\t\"%s\" by %s (%d:0%d)\n", s[i]->title, s[i]->artist, min, sec);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    // This is test data
    static char *TITLES[] = { "Back 2 Life", "Loneliness For Love", "Desire 126", "Perfect", "In My Head",
                             "Old Skool Love", "Let's Go", "No Place", "We Gotta Go", "How You Get the Girl",
                             "Catch", "Here Tonight", "Details", "Dangerous", "Brighter Than the Sun",
                             "Photograph", "Thinking Out Loud", "If Heaven Were to Fall", "I Just Wanna Be With You",
                             "Song Sung Blue", "Outta Style", "Why", };

    static char *ARTISTS[] = { "E-Type", "Lovely the Band", "Hollerado", "Ed Sheeran", "Ryland James",
                              "Divine Brown", "Group 1 Crew", "Backstreet Boys", "E-Type", "Taylor Swift",
                              "Brett Young", "Brett Young", "Billy Currington", "Kardinal Offichall",
                              "Colbie Caillat", "Ed Sheeran", "Ed Sheeran", "E-Type", "E-Type", "Neil Diamond",
                              "Aaron Watson", "Frankie Avalon", };

    static int   DURATIONS[] = { 217, 237, 187, 263, 205, 204, 256, 179, 213, 247, 196,
                                216, 201, 251, 231, 202, 281, 223, 230, 185, 222, 161 };


    static char *TEST_USER_NAMES[NUM_TEST_USERS] = { "Disco Stew", "Peter Punk", "Country Candy", "Ronnie Rocker",
                                                    "Sleeping Sam", "Disco Stew", "Mellow Marvin" };

    static int  LIST_SIZES[NUM_TEST_USERS] = { 7, 9, 9, 5, 1, 0, 0 };
    static int  SONGNUMS[NUM_TEST_USERS][MAX_SONGS_PER_USER] = {
                                   {1, 2, 4, 5, 12, 15, 21}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 9, 13, 14, 17, 20},
                                   {6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21}, {0, 8, 16, 17, 18}, {19}, {0}, {0} };


    // Create the TuneShare Center
    TuneShare   tuneShareCenter;
    tuneShareCenter.numUsers = 0;

    // Attempt to register all test users
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEST_USERS; i++) {
        if (!registerUser(&tuneShareCenter, TEST_USER_NAMES[i]))
            printf("Error adding User: \"%s\"\n", TEST_USER_NAMES[i]);
        else
            printf("User: \"%s\" has been registered\n", TEST_USER_NAMES[i]);
    }
    
    // Display some stats
    displayStats(&tuneShareCenter);

    // Log on a user
    printf("\nLogging on a user...\n");
    logon(&tuneShareCenter, "Disco Stew");
    // Display some stats
    displayStats(&tuneShareCenter);

    // Now add all the test songs for these test users
    for (int i = 0; i < tuneShareCenter.numUsers; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LIST_SIZES[i]; j++)
            addSong(tuneShareCenter.users[i], TITLES[SONGNUMS[i][j]], ARTISTS[SONGNUMS[i][j]], DURATIONS[SONGNUMS[i][j]]);
    }
    
    // Display some stats
    displayStats(&tuneShareCenter);

}
```

This gives the correct output I need. Just like this.
[image: Correct Output]

But when I free the allocated memory from the heap using **free()** function as an example in the function **int registerUser(TuneShare *t, char *name)** it does not give the output at all,

```
int registerUser(TuneShare *t, char *name)
{
    short int numUsers = t->numUsers;

    if (numUsers == MAX_USERS)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if(numUsers >= 1)
            //printf("%s \n", t->users[0]->name);
        for (int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++)
        {
            User *u = t->users[i];
            char *uName = u->name;
            if (uName == name)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            //free(u);
        }
        User *temp;
        if ((temp = malloc(sizeof *temp)) != NULL)
        {
            temp->name = name;
            temp->numSongs = 0;
            temp->online = '0';
        }
        
        t->users[numUsers] = temp;

        t->numUsers = numUsers + 1;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Here is the output when I use **free()** as above.

[image]

I do not understand what is the problem. If anyone could help me it would be amazing.

Comment: Why would you free the memory for user’s names as you examine them? You need a record of a user’s name as long as you are keeping information about that user. You do not free it until you are discarded information about a user.

Comment: Also, you cannot properly compare strings with `uName == name`. That compares the pointers to the strings. Two strings may be the same even if they are recorded in different places. You can use `strcmp` to compare strings, or you can compare them by comparing the characters in them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply @EricPostpischil . The assignment says that I cannot have any memory leaks. Isn't it a memory leak if I do not use free(). And also is there a better method that I can use to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeing a pointer is like erasing its content from memory, so when you free temp, you are deleting the new User, so t->users (aka tuneShareCenter.users) will be full of useless "empty" User pointers.

You should free the users at the end of the main function, freeing tuneShareCenter and the songs with something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tuneShareCenter.numUsers; i++) {
    User* tUser = tuneShareCenter.users[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < tUser->numSongs; j++){
        free(tUser->songs[j]);
    }
    free(tUser);
}
free(tuneShareCenter);
```

(I hope I wrote it correctly)

Comment: Thank you very much @javgat this was very helpful to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you might be misunderstanding is that calling `free(temp)` releases the object in memory pointed to by `temp` - it doesn't really have anything to do with the `temp` variable itself.  `temp` will be deallocated once the function returns.  In fact, declaring `temp` itself might even be unnecessary.

```
int registerUser(TuneShare *t, char *name)
{
    int i;

    if (t->numUsers >= MAX_USERS)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < t->numUsers; i++)
        if (strcmp(t->users[i]->name, name) == 0)
            return 0;

    if ((t->users[t->numUsers] = malloc(sizeof User)) == NULL)
        return 0;

    t->users[t->numUsers]->name = name;
    t->users[t->numUsers]->numSongs = 0;
    t->users[t->numUsers]->online = '0';    

    t->numUsers++;
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @greenBox for the reply. Now it is becoming a bit clear. If I do it like this as you have given, isn't it going to be a memory leak? When I run it in visual studio with **crtdbg** it shows there is a memory leak. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: I can't say for certain why visual studio is reporting that there is a leak, since I'm not using visual studio myself.  It's possible that by adding another operation in your program that deletes a user, which would require a call to `free`, would solve the problem.